# How to set an EditText to empty with a number input type

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

I have tried

```
editText.setText("");
```

however I get an error saying "" is not a valid integer. I have also tryed changing the input type to text setting the text to "" than changing the input type back to numbers but I get the same error.

Comment: how are you setting the input type? if you set it in the xml there shouldn't be a problem with using `setText("")`. I'm not sure about if it is set programmatically in java though.

Comment: Its set in xml    android:inputType="number"

Comment: Odd. I thought you could use setText("") with the type being "number". Though SefanoMunarini has come up with a nice solution it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
editText.setText("0", BufferType.EDITABLE); /*// May be unecessary... */
editText.getText().clear();
```

You may need to set the buffer type to BufferType.EDITABLE first...

Answer (score 3):

In XML use properties

```
android:hint=""
android:inputType="number"
```

In code use

```
.setHint("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty string value in res/values/string.xml, like
    --> < string name:"empty_string">< /string>

Answer (score 0):

Set the prperties in XML as

> android:hint = ""

In Java

> editText.setHint("");